# Inserting and updating database using sortable list

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

There are many examples of updating a database using a jQuery sortable list which involves serializing the `id` of the list and then updating the database based on that `id` sequence.

Now the problem is that I want to use a jQuery sortable connected list for both inserting into and updating the database. I have two lists.

Source list:

```html
<ul id="admin_news_all">
    <li id="2588" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2678" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2680" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2690" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2692" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2694" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2696" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2698" class="ui-draggable">
    <li iid="2696" class="ui-draggable">
    <li id="2704" class="ui-draggable">
</ul>
```

Target list:

```html
<ul id="news_box_top" class="ui-sortable">
    <li class="ui-draggable" style="display: list-item; id="2686"">
    <li class="ui-draggable" style="display: list-item; id="2496"">
</ul>
```

I have initialized the jQuery as:

```js
$("#news_box_top").sortable()
$("#admin_news_all li").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    connectToSortable:'#news_box_top'
});
```

Now I want move items from the source list to the target list, and then altering (both inserting and updating operations) the database on click of a `button` element.

Target database: MySql

```
id int(12), position int(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your second list should be like this :

```
<ul id="news_box_top" class="ui-sortable">
  <li class="ui-draggable" id="2686" style="display: list-item; ">
  <li class="ui-draggable" id="2496" style="display: list-item; ">
</ul>
```

Then I assume you know how to update your database, I just give an hand to build an array whit sorted ids :

```
ids = [];
$('#news_box_top li.ui-draggable').toArray().forEach( function (el) {
  // Here I assume the element has an id
  ids.push( $(el).attr('id') );
});
```